# Should I include “as a” for every item in a list of jobs, or just the first item?

Tags: ellipsis, parallelism, lists

I have a doubt: should I write:

> 1. I worked as a teacher, as housekeeper manager, as a Rep, etc.

or

> 2. I worked as a teacher, housekeeper manager, Rep, etc.

Comment: Did you intentionally omit "a" before "housekeeper manager" in the first example?

Comment: @Jasper: Good point. For bonus points, can you think of *any* context where a "deleted" term could "validly" be *re-introduced" in a subsequent element within such a list? Offhand, I can't.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: "JQ Adams served as a Senator, as President, and as a Representative." Sounds correct to me to drop the article in front of President, even in a list, but perhaps technically incorrect.

Comment: @MatthewW: I'm not sure "technically incorrect" means anything here. But your example sounds fine to me, so *you* get the bonus points (or at least, a comment upvote, which is the best I can offer! :)

Answer (score 11):

Both versions are syntactically fine, but idiomatically native speakers would tend to "delete" all "highly predictable" repetitions of ***as a*** in such contexts (or at the very least, delete repeated ***as***).

There's a *slightly* greater chance that the more verbose version would be understood as meaning *I've had **several different jobs** - for example [blah blah]*, where the shorter version could be interpreted as *My job involved covering **several different roles** - for example [blah blah]*. But that might be because we always tend to look for a more "unusual" interpretation if someone uses less common phrasing, not because of anything inherent in the words themselves.

---

Per the comment to the question (OP's current text omits ***a*** from the second item in the list, in case that gets edited out later), I should point out that it's ***very*** unusual (some might say "invalid") to delete any repeated element from such a "list" ***and then re-introduce it in a subsequent element***. You should probably assume you *never* want to do that.